# Swift's Age of the indices in a Set

Tags: swift

If I set up a set

```
var mySet: Set<Int> = [1,2,3,4]
```

The first of the indices can be printed (although the same is for any of them in this particular set)

```
print (mySet.indices.first)
```

Which gives the output in the console of:

```
Optional(Swift.Set<Swift.Int>.Index(_variant: Swift.Set<Swift.Int>.Index._Variant.native(Swift._HashTable.Index(bucket: Swift._HashTable.Bucket(offset: 0), age: -654554875))))
```

Wo what does the `age` section of this mean? I can't find any reference in the documentation to age - what is the age of? What is it for? Where is the documentation for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not part of the public API, but you can find it in the [source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/SetStorage.swift#L60):

```
internal class __RawSetStorage: __SwiftNativeNSSet {

    // ...
    /// A mutation count, enabling stricter index validation.
    @usableFromInline
    @nonobjc
    internal final var _age: Int32
      // ...

}
```

As an example, indices become invalid after a set is mutated (like in all collections). For a set this is verified using the age of a set and its indices, as one can see in [NativeSet.siwft](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/NativeSet.swift):

```
func validatedBucket(for index: _HashTable.Index) -> Bucket {
    _precondition(hashTable.isOccupied(index.bucket) && index.age == age,
    "Attempting to access Set elements using an invalid index")
    return index.bucket
}
```

Example:

```
var set: Set = [1, 2, 3]

let idx = set.startIndex
print(set[idx])
set.insert(4)
print(set[idx])
// Fatal error: Attempting to access Set elements using an invalid index
```